# login not working

Tags: 20.04

I can't login to Ubuntu despite the correct password on my GUI desktop.In order to change my password I went to recovery mode and used the command " passwd username" but it displayed " passwd [options] [login] and listed some options such as "-S , -e , -d".In one of the methods I found included using "ls /home" to see the accounts but in my case the username "user" was  displayed whereas the username to my account is something else

Comment: You've not said if you're asking about a 20.04 Desktop GUI login, or 20.04 Server (TUI) login. If you can login using a text terminal then your password is not the issue, but a GUI login requires more than correct password (eg. lack of disk space in $HOME will cause login to fail & login is cancelled, ie. login-loop). Your provided details are *unclear*; is this a server? or desktop?  text to GUI login?   FYI:  If something has happened to your $HOME (home directory), then login-loop would be expected for a GUI login, but you didn't specify...

Comment: The issue is I can't login to my account on my desktop although the password entered is correct and when I used the method of going into recovery mode  it didn't work when I used the command passwd username it displays the line    " passwd [options] [login]"and lists some commands some of which include -S ,-e ,-d. and in one of methods I found included that we can use " ls /home" to see the accounts but it didn't list my username but a different one.

Comment: You can't login using the text terminal?    If you have a GUI login failure; the first thing to do is login using text terminal & correct space etc. issues, but you've still not been clear if your issue relates to a GUI (desktop) system or TUI (server or desktop system)..   This isn't a forum (but a Q&A site), please amend your question with additional details, as comments are from readers to the OP (*Original Poster*) and get deleted once addressed

Comment: Can you switch to text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 for example) and login there?   If you have no issues with your password, you'll be able to login using the text terminal.  You can also fix other issues that will prevent a GUI login from occurring (*which are unrelated to password, but usually the result of lack of disk space in $HOME or your user directory, or system changes made in the last session where GUI was used*).

Comment: I mean that after the command passwd username it is supposed to ask to enter new password but it doesn't in my case instead it displays this line " passwd [options][login] and I tried using text terminal but it displayed on the screen that the password was incorrect

Comment: sorry I mixed the terms when we boot our PC if there is a separate partition for Ubuntu we get "Advanced options for Ubuntu" through there we can enter recovery mode and then from a bunch of options choose root where we see a CLI and can change the password using mount -rw -o remount / then using passwd username(where one adds their username)